# Preview pane location, AX2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, preview-pane

I have created a preview pane, but the location is in the factbox area (right side).

How can I get it in the bottom of the form?

[Wrong location, I need it in the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N87UG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to: Add a Preview Pane to a List Page [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc574825.aspx)

Comment: It's not at listpage, it my own form i have created. I have been told, that it is only possible with List Pages ?

Comment: @Mshei you can set the PartLocation on the Part reference

Comment: Yes, but when i change it to 'preview pane'  it transforms to preview pane. But the location still remains in the factbox area (right side). I need to change the location to the bottom of my grid.